# Equivalent of fgets (c language) in Android

Tags: android

I want to read a line from a text file.  In c `fgets()` in used.  Is any equivalent of `fgets()` in Android.

Comment: [BufferedReader.readLine()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine())

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [BufferedReader.readLine()](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.io/BufferedReaderreadLine.htm) ,  [InputStream](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadInputStreamtostring.htm) Class ,[BufferedInputStream](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0180__File/BufferedInputStream.htm) Class.  And also [DataInputStream](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/ReadingBytesfromaDataInputStream.htm) Class for reading data in Bytes.